# I have static noise in my speakers and headset

Tags: audio, noise

I have been having a problem with my computer where I am constantly getting static from the point I turn on my PC.

I have changed Towers, Hard Drives, added and removed a Sound Blaster Xtreme Sound Card, used 3 different Headsets, and 2 sets of speakers. Lately I have noticed random dips in my frame rates when playing games.

Is there any possibility that the graphics card could be causing the static noise with the possibility of it needing to go in for repairs?

Specs:

- i5-3570K 3.40 GHZ
- Gigabyte GTX 570
- 8GB of Corsair Ram
- MB ASUS|P8Z77-V Z77
- 3TB Seagate Barracude HDD
- Rosewill 850W PSU
- Corsair A70 Heatsink

Comment: Welcome to Superuser, I edited your question to be a bit more readable. If you dislike it or want to add something, feel free to revert my changes or edit it again.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure when the post was made, but this could help future viewers . I was having the same problem a couple of years ago. Turns out all I had to do was go into my computers volume control and mute the microphone. Worth a try first.

Answer (score 0):

There's a HUGE number of sources for static... and the fixes are not always as simple or cost-effective as you would hope.

Why you seem to want to blame the video-card for interference with the sound card is a bit strange to me.  It's also strange that you decided to bring up frame-rates with regards to a question about your sound-card.

A few bits missing from this discussion are things like:

What kind and how much static are you talking about?  constant hum? background hiss? hiss & pops? random distortions?  Describe it as best as you can.  "static" means a lot of different things to different people.

When are you hearing the static?   constantly? only when playing music?  only when playing games? only when loud? only when quiet? only when the system is taxed?  ???

What kind of connection to these headsets/speakers are you talking about?  (3.5mm plugs? USB? Optical cable? Wireless? Bluetooth?)

These are just *some* contributing factors to static.  More info is needed.

Comment: Sorry about the lack of information.

as far as the static goes, it is a constant hum that is going on from the second i turn on the computer to the second i turn it off, so i drown it out with music and games. There are some randoms distortions from time to time as well.

The speakers i used were a 3.5mm plug, and the 1st headset was an optical cable plugged into the sound card ( both the headset and the sound card have been returned) the second headset was 2 3.5mm jacks and the current one is 2 3.5mm jacks with usb (Turtle Beach).

Comment: it sounds like a faulty ground someplace.  i.e. ground has voltage on it... Could be anything from: the common-ground feeding your whole building isn't attached to anything... or perhaps your building has something shorted out and it is putting some voltage on the ground... or extreme RF noise... or who knows.  That's one of the more difficult issues to track down and fix properly.